# Is there any way I can delete all the rows from database before altering the model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I want to alter my model but before doing so I want to delete all the records from my database, is there any dajngo ORM query for doing that cuz I don't want to do it manually.
Thanks.

I tried to alter my model but when I migrated the changes an error occured.
it was a long error but the last line was this.

`File "C:\\Users\\ALI SHANAWER.virtualenvs\\PiikFM-App-Backend-O_dKS6jY\\Lib\\site-packages\\MySQLdb\\connections.py", line 254, in query \_mysql.connection.query(self, query) django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3140, 'Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column '#sql-45_2d01.qbo_class'.')`
any one knows what this is?

Comment: run 'truncate table <table_name> in your db shell, or run MyModel.objects.all().delete() in django shell

Answer (score 0):

You can simple delete db.sqlite ie, database file 
then run python manage.py makemigration and then python manage.py migrate. 

I hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate only a single table then use {ModelName}.objects.all().delete() otherwise use can use "python manage.py flush" for truncate database.